# Como acessar a propriedade data-opened de cada div que esta dentro de um array ? Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como acessar a propriedade data-opened de cada div que esta dentro de um array ?

```
<div class='bares' data-opened=1></div>
    <div class='bares' data-opened=2></div>
    <div class='bares' data-opened=3></div>
    <div class='bares' data-opened=4></div>

    var bares = new Array();
    $('.bares').each(function(){
     bares.push($(this));
    })

    for (i = 0; i <= bares.length; i++){
    // como exibir alert da propriedade data-opened de cada div ?
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa desse `FOR` mesmo? Só com o `each` você consegue o que quer.

```
var bares = new Array();

$('.bares').each(function(){
    var opened = $(this).data('opened');
    alert(opened);
});
```

Caso precise mesmo...

```
var bares = new Array();

$('.bares').each(function(){
    bares = bares.push($(this));
});

for (i = 0; i <= bares.length; i++){
    alert(bares.data('opened'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode pegar o `data-opened` de cada elemento adicionado na array desta forma:

```
  bares[i].data('opened')
    ↑   ↑
array   índice
```

Agora o `i <= bares.length` está incorreto. Você deve usar apenas o `<` (e não `<=`) porque o laço deve ir até o tamanho da array - 1:

```js
var bares = new Array();

$('.bares').each(function(){
   bares.push($(this));
})

for (i = 0; i < bares.length; i++){
   alert(bares[i].data('opened'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='bares' data-opened=1></div>
<div class='bares' data-opened=2></div>
<div class='bares' data-opened=3></div>
<div class='bares' data-opened=4></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bares = new Array();
  $('.bares').each(function() {
    bares.push($(this));
  });
  for (i = 0; i < bares.length; i++) {
    console.log(bares[i].attr('data-opened'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='bares' data-opened=1></div>
<div class='bares' data-opened=2></div>
<div class='bares' data-opened=3></div>
<div class='bares' data-opened=4></div>
```

Faz uma pequena alteração no seu for para `i < bares.length` e em seguida através do índice só acessar a propriedade através do [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
for (i = 0; i < bares.length; i++){
        console.log(bares[i].attr('data-opened'));
    }
```